# Javascript e asp.net [vb] webforms session

Tags: javascript, asp.net, session

Tenho um metodo em javascript que retorna uma string, 
No caso:

```
var hash = PagSeguroDirectPayment.getSenderHash();
```

como colocar esta variavel hash em uma session e ler esta session no asp.

```
Dim hash as string =  Session("sessionDoHashExemplo").toString
```

ou existe outro meio (sem usar post/get) de passar esta informação para o asp.

o codigo acima esta em um arquivo .js separado, e nao posso usar um input hidden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não é possível, `Session's` de `server-side` e `client-side` não tem comunicação entre si, A solução encontrada foi alocar os resultados em `hiddenfields` e manipular a informação através deles.